# Tkinter: ¿ Como obtener el ancho de una línea?

Tags: tkinter

Estoy trabajando con la librería de tkinter, y no tengo un ejemplo que mostrar, es algo teórico, quiero saber cómo puede obtener el número de caracteres de una línea, ya sea del widget scrolltext, o tk.text.

Mi idea es leer línea por línea del contenido de scrolltext, eso ya sabria como plantearlo, y lo que quiero es que si una línea empieza por # toda esa línea me la marque de un color diferente, es posible recoger el ancho de una línea ??

```
from textwrap import wrap
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import END, scrolledtext as sc
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("RECORRER")

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#3fd1cb',width=500, height=500)
frame.pack(
    expand=0,
    fill=tk.BOTH
)

list_text = [
    "Hola primer text", 
    "Hola segundo text", 
    "#Hola tengo sorpresa",
    "Chao"
]

text = sc.ScrolledText(
    frame,
    wrap= tk.WORD
)
text.pack(expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH, padx=20, pady=20)

for t in list_text:
    text.insert(tk.END, '\n'+t)

def colour_line():
    linea = '#'
    indx = '1.0'
    if linea:
        print (linea)
        while True:
            indx = text.search(
                    linea, indx, nocase=1, stopindex=tk.END)
            print(indx)
            if not indx:
                break
            lastidx = '%s+%dc' % (indx, len(linea))
            text.tag_add(
                'found1', indx, lastidx
            )
            indx = lastidx


            print(indx)

    text.tag_config(
        'found1', 
        foreground='dodgerblue',
        font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold')
    )
colour_line()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ves en la imagen solo me pone en NEGRITA y cambia el color en #, yo quiero en toda la linea.

Comment: Si ya estás recorriendo el texto linea por linea, puedes usar simplemente len(linea)

Comment: Creo que lo intente, voy hacer un ejemplo practico, y probare de nuevo, y paso el código haber en que fallo.

Comment: @DanteS. He puesto un ejemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no tienes ganas de obtener todo el contenido del widget e iterar sobre el, puedes hacerlo del siguiente modo:

###### Código

```
import tkinter as tk

text = tk.Text()
text.insert("end", "hola mundo\n")
text.insert("end", "# hola mundo\n")
text.insert("end", "# hola mundo\n")
text.insert("end", "hola mundo\n")

text.tag_configure("blue", foreground="blue")

# obtenemos la posición del ultimo caracter en formato 'linea.columna'
end = text.index("end")

# obtenemos el numero de linea y lo convertimos en entero
line_count = int(end.split(".", 1)[0])

# Iteramos desde 1 hasta la ultima linea más 1.
for line in range(1, line_count+1):
    # Creamos el indice que nos indicará el principio de la linea.
    # Esto obtiene la posición del primer caracter en la linea especificada.
    startline = f"{line}.0"

    # si se encuentra en el rango 'linea.0' y 'linea.1' el caracter "#".
    # Esto devuelve la posición de la cadena encontrada si tiene exito
    # y si no devuelve una cadena vacía.
    if(text.search("#", startline, stopindex=f"{line}.1")):
        # generamos el indice que indica el final de la linea.
        # linea.end significa el final de la linea.
        endline = f"{line}.end"
        
        text.tag_add("blue", startline, endline)

text.pack()
```

###### Produce

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

###### Referencias

- https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text-methods.html
- https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text-index.html

Comment: Como siempre muchas gracias Dante, quedo estupendo.

Comment: Me leere las referencias, gracias.

Comment: De nada LOPUMA c: